# Error when compiling GUI program in Qt creator: Cannot load library libClangCodeModel.so

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

When I create a console program in Qt Creator, I can't run it from my system terminal.

I am using **manjaro Linux** .

And I can't create GUI programs because of this error:

```
home/ramigamal/Programs/qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/
              plugins/QtProject/libClangCodeModel.so: Cannot load library 
/home/ramigamal/Programs/qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/
              plugins/QtProject/libClangCodeModel.so: 
  (libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what you already tried, so that it is more clear on where the issue might be.

Comment: The error comes from qtcreator plugin loading, not from the app itself.

Comment: How I fix this plugin error ? @FrankOsterfeld

Comment: The program dosnt reseve my inputs .

Answer (score 0):

create symlink which didn't exist : 
*locate libtinfo.so*

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/libtinfo.so.5 /path/to/libtinfo.so
```